# Animate Table append Rows from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table tab which consists thead part and an Array of objects with elements which are actually table tbody rows.

```
var tab = $("#myTab");

var arr = [tr, tr, tr,...]

<tr>
    <td>Chris</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>single</td>
</tr>
...
```

I append 'em with for loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    tab.append(arr[i]);
}
```

I would like to animate this, something like to display this row by row appending slowly.

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you looking for:

```js
var tab = $("#myTab");

tr = "<tr> <td>Chris</td>  <td>25</td>  <td>single</td></tr>"

var arr = [tr, tr, tr]
var i = 0;

var inter = setInterval(function() {
    if (i < arr.length) {

      tab.append(arr[i]);
      tab.find('tr:last-child').hide() //hide the row
      tab.find('tr:last-child').show('slow') //show the row
      i++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(inter)
    }
  }, 1000) //milli-second gap you want to give
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTab" border="1">

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use interval for your code

```
 setInterval(function () { 
for(var I=0; I < arr.length; I++) {
      tab.append(arr[I]);
 }, 10000);
```

This code append row in 10 sec interval

Answer (score 1):

```js
var _container = $("#container");

var _tr = "<tr><td> Chris <br/></td><td> 25 <br/></td><td> Single <br/></td></tr>";

var _arr = [_tr, _tr, _tr, _tr, _tr, _tr, _tr, _tr, _tr, _tr, _tr, _tr, _tr, _tr, _tr];

function addRows() {     
     if(_arr.length) {         
       _container.append(_arr.pop());
       _container.find("tr:last").hide();

     
       _container.find("tr:last").fadeIn(2400, addRows);
     }
}

addRows();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="container">
</table >
```

Comment: I particularly like the callback from the fadeIn being used to kick off the next row. I went for something similar, but used a timeout, which allows the fade and add to overlap: http://jsfiddle.net/_sir/t16tkryL/1/